# Matplotlib: Hysteresis loop using Mirrored or Split x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

In an experiment, a load cell advances in equal increments of distance with time, compresses a sample; stops when a specified distance from the start point is reached; then retracts in equal increments of distance with time back to the starting position.

A plot of pressure (load cell reading) on the y axis against pressure on the x axis produces a familiar hysteresis loop. A plot of pressure (load cell reading) on the y axis against time on the x axis produces an assymetric peak with the maximum pressure in the centre, corresponding to the maximum advancement point of the sensor.

Instead of the above, I'd like to plot pressure on the y axis against distance on the x axis, with the additional constraint that the x axis is labelled starting at 0, with maximum pressure at the middle of the x axis, and 0 again at the right hand end of the x-axis. In other words, the curve will be identical in shape to the plot of pressure v time, but will be of pressure v distance, where the left half of the plot indicates the distance of the probe from its starting position during advancement; and the right half of the plot indicates distance of the probe from its starting position during retraction.

My actual datasets contain thousands of rows of data but by way of illustration, a minimal dummy dataset would look something like the following, where the 3 columns correspond to Time, Distance of probe from origin, and Pressure measured by probe respectively:

```
[
[0,0,0],
[1,2,10],
[2,4,30],
[3,6,60],
[4,4,35],
[5,2,15],
[6,0,0]
]
```

I can't work out how to get MatPlotlib to construct the x-axis so that the range goes from 0 to a maximum, then back to 0 again. I'd be grateful for advice on how to achieve this plot in the most simple and elegant way. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: Have found a workaround to the problem of rounding ticks to the nearest integer by using the `np.around` function which rounds decimals to the nearest even value, to a specified number of decimal places (default = 0): e.g. 1.5 and 2.5 round to 2.0, -0.5 and 0.5 round to 0.0, etc. More info here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.around.html

So berna1111's code becomes:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Time, Distance, Pressure
data = [[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1.9, 10], # Dummy data including decimals to demonstrate rounding
        [2, 4.1, 30],
        [3, 6.1, 60],
        [4, 3.9, 35],
        [5, 1.9, 15],
        [6, -0.2, 0]]

# convert to array to allow indexing like [i, j]
data = np.array(data)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

max_ticks = 10
skip = (data.shape[0] / max_ticks) + 1
ax.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 2])  # Pressure(time)
ax.set_xticks(data[::skip, 0])
ax.set_xticklabels(np.absolute(np.around((data[::skip, 1]))))  # Pressure(Distance(time)); rounded to nearest integer
ax.set_ylabel('Pressure [Pa?]')
ax.set_xlabel('Distance [m?]')
fig.show()
```

According to the numpy documentation, `np.around` should round the final value of -0.2 for Distance to '0.0'; however it seems to round to '-0.0' instead. Not sure why this occurs, but since all my xticklabels in this particular case need to be positive integers or zero, I can correct this behaviour by using the `np.absolute` function as shown above. Everything now seems to work OK for my requirements, but if I'm missing something, or there's a better solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

As you have time, you can use it for the x axis values and just change the x tick labels:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Time, Distance, Pressure
data = [[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 10],
        [2, 4, 30],
        [3, 6, 60],
        [4, 4, 35],
        [5, 2, 15],
        [6, 0, 0]]

# convert to array to allow indexing like [i, j]
data = np.array(data)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

max_ticks = 10
skip = (data.shape[0] / max_ticks) + 1
ax.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 2])  # Pressure(time)
ax.set_xticks(data[::skip, 0])
ax.set_xticklabels(data[::skip, 1])  # Pressure(Distance(time)) ?
ax.set_ylabel('Pressure [Pa?]')
ax.set_xlabel('Distance [m?]')
fig.show()
```

[image: Pressure as a function of distance]
The `skip` is just so you don't end up with too many ticks on the plot, change as you like.

As said in comment, the above only holds for uniforme changes in distance as a function of time. For non uniform changes, you'll have to use something like:

```
data = [[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 10],
        [2, 4, 30],
        [3, 6, 60],
        [3.5, 5.4, 40],
        [4, 4, 35],
        [5, 2, 15],
        [6, 0, 0]]
# convert to array to allow indexing like [i, j]
data = np.array(data)


def find_max_pos(data, column=0):
    return np.argmax(data[:, column])


def reverse_unload(data, unload_start):
    # prepare new_data with new column:
    new_shape = np.array(data.shape)
    new_shape[1] += 1
    new_data = np.empty(new_shape)
    # copy all correct data
    new_data[:, 0] = data[:, 0]
    new_data[:, 1] = data[:, 1]
    new_data[:, 2] = data[:, 2]
    new_data[:unload_start+1, 3] = data[:unload_start+1, 1]
    # use gradient to fill the rest
    gradient = -np.gradient(data[:, 1])
    for i in range(unload_start + 1, data.shape[0]):
        new_data[i, 3] = new_data[i-1, 3] + gradient[i]
    return new_data


data = reverse_unload(data, find_max_pos(data, 1))

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

max_ticks = 10
skip = (data.shape[0] / max_ticks) + 1
ax.plot(data[:, 3], data[:, 2])  # Pressure("Distance")
ax.set_xticks(data[::skip, 3])
ax.set_xticklabels(data[::skip, 1])
ax.grid()  # added for clarity
ax.set_ylabel('Pressure [Pa?]')
ax.set_xlabel('Distance [m?]')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Regarding the fact that using the measured values as the ticks results in these not being round nice numbers, I found it was just easier to map the automatic ticks from `matplotlib` to the correct values:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = [[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 2, 10],
        [2, 4, 30],
        [3, 6, 60],
        [3.5, 5.4, 40],
        [4, 4, 35],
        [5, 2, 15],
        [6, 0, 0]]
# convert to array to allow indexing like [i, j]
data = np.array(data)


def find_max_pos(data, column=0):
    return np.argmax(data[:, column])


def reverse_unload(data):
    unload_start = find_max_pos(data, 1)
    # prepare new_data with new column:
    new_shape = np.array(data.shape)
    new_shape[1] += 1
    new_data = np.empty(new_shape)
    # copy all correct data
    new_data[:, 0] = data[:, 0]
    new_data[:, 1] = data[:, 1]
    new_data[:, 2] = data[:, 2]
    new_data[:unload_start+1, 3] = data[:unload_start+1, 1]
    # use gradient to fill the rest
    gradient = data[unload_start:-1, 1]-data[unload_start+1:, 1]
    for i, j in enumerate(range(unload_start + 1, data.shape[0])):
        new_data[j, 3] = new_data[j-1, 3] + gradient[i]
    return new_data


def create_map_function(data):
    """
    Return function that maps values of distance
    folded over the maximum pressure applied.
    """
    max_index = find_max_pos(data, 1)
    x0, y0 = data[max_index, 1], data[max_index, 1]
    x1, y1 = 2*data[max_index, 1], 0
    m = (y1 - y0) / (x1 - x0)
    b = y0 - m*x0

    def map_function(x):
        if x < x0:
            return x
        else:
            return m*x+b

    return map_function


def process_data(data):
    data = reverse_unload(data)
    map_function = create_map_function(data)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(data[:, 3], data[:, 2])
    ax.set_xticklabels([map_function(x) for x in ax.get_xticks()])
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_ylabel('Pressure [Pa?]')
    ax.set_xlabel('Distance [m?]')
    fig.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_data(data)
```

[image]

Comment: Just noticed this only works if the distance increments with time are equal, otherwise the distances between distance values won't be properly scaled.

Comment: Many thanks for your rapid & helpful response. Your simpler (first) solution works OK on my real data, but the only problem is that the new x-ticks are: 
0, 1.019, 2.039, 3.039, 3.943, 2.923, 1.903, 0.883, -0.137; whereas I'd like the x-ticks to occur on integer values of; 0,1,2,3,4,3,2,1,0.  
Is it possible to modify your code to force the X ticks to round to the nearest integer?
(my raw data run in regular increments:  0, 0.005, 0.01, 0.015, 0.02... s for time and 0, 0.004 ,0.009, 0.014, 0.019... mm for Distance; but the Distance values don't coincide neatly with integer values).

Comment: That problem is visible on the second example, I should have thought about it... Maybe it would be easier to map the automatic values found by matplotlib (which you can get using [`get_xticks`](https://matplotlib.org/devdocs/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_xticks.html)) and use a function to convert them to the 'real' values.

Comment: Many thanks for clear and helpful examples - will investigate mapping function and get_xticks. BW.